# Checkboxes with codeigniter and border thickness

Tags: javascript, html, css

Any ideas why my form checkbox isn't looking like the template. Also seems as if the border between the middle section of the form and the bottom section of the form is thicker on my page.

http://www.kansasoutlawwrestling.com/kowmanager/

http://www.kansasoutlawwrestling.com/peach/Template/login.html

Any ideas?

```
<div class="top">
<div class="gradient"></div>
<div class="white"></div>
<div class="shadow"></div>
</div>
<div class="content">
<h1>KOW MANAGER | LOGIN</h1>
<div class="background"></div>
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="box">
        <div class="header grey">
            <img src="<?php echo base_url() ?>assets/img/icons/packs/fugue/16x16/lock.png" width="16" height="16" />
            <h3>Login</h3>
        </div>
        <?php echo form_open('') ?>
        <div class="content no-padding grey">
            <div class="section _100">
                <?php echo form_label('Username', 'username'); ?>            
                <div>
                    <?php echo form_input('username', set_value('username'), 'class=required'); ?>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="section _100">
                <?php echo form_label('Password', 'password'); ?>
                <div>     
                    <?php echo form_password('password', '', 'class=required'); ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="actions">
            <div class="actions-left" style="margin-top: 8px;">
                <?php echo form_label( form_checkbox( 'autologin' ) . ' Auto-login in future' ); ?>
            </div>
            <div class="actions-right">
                <?php echo form_submit(array('id' => 'submit', 'name' => 'submit'), 'Login!'); ?>           
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php echo form_close(); ?>
    </div>
    <div class="shadow"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: You have to add style for checkbox to make it look like the second one.

Answer (score 1):

One uses a standard HTML checkbox, the other uses a scripted replacement that swaps images, but provides checkbox functionality.

Comment: I know this but I'm trying to figure out what I"m doing wrong so that it will work properly.

Comment: There is likely some JS code looking for a particular class or ID on the page. It then replaces the checkbox with the image-based cose.

Answer (score 0):

To remove the border you need this in your css:

```
.box .actions{
    border-top: none;
}
```

Comment: Is that how the template has it though? I don't really want to be messing with css. There has to be a reason with the css the same for it to not have that border there the same. Its a minor issue that's bothering me.

Comment: Sorry I can't help with the template, I don't know why your page is different.